# How can I create a foreach loop with "Foreach From Variable Enumerator" in SSIS programmatically

Tags: ssis, biml

I'm trying to create an SSIS package dynamically using DTS Runtime classes.
I'm trying to create a foreach loop using "Foreach From Variable Enumerator", where my variable contains an ArrayList with the necessary collection.

I'm unable to find a way through which i can set the variable (under enumerator configuration, as seen in VS) which will hold the collection for looping.

I'm not finding any options in forEachLoop.ForEachEnumerator. Nor am I able to cast forEachEnumeratorHost.InnerObject to an enumerator I want. I found on MSDN a class Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Enumerators.FromVar.ForEachFromVarEnumerator. But I'm not able to find the FromVar class in Enumerators. Am i missing something grave?

Has anyone else done this? I find it difficult to believe that something which can be done so easily through Visual Studio UI, cannot be done programmatically.

Below is the code I have now...

> ForEachLoop forEachLoop = p.Executables.Add("STOCK:FOREACHLOOP") as
>   ForEachLoop;
>
> // Create a VariableMappings and VariableMapping objects.
>     ForEachVariableMapping forEachVariableMapping =
>   forEachLoop.VariableMappings.Add();
>
> // Create a mapping between the variable and its value.
>     forEachVariableMapping.VariableName = @"User::CurrentTableName";
>     forEachVariableMapping.ValueIndex = 0;
>
> ForEachEnumeratorInfo forEachEnumeratorInfo =
>   runtimeApp.ForEachEnumeratorInfos["Foreach From Variable Enumerator"];
>     ForEachEnumeratorHost forEachEnumeratorHost =
>   forEachEnumeratorInfo.CreateNew();

Comment: Are you using ssis or biml? And are you using a script task?

Comment: I'm doing all the above in an ssis package script task

Comment: Dts.Variable["User::YourNameList"].Value = Your ArrayList- And then you map it in ssis under foreach loop container as a variable enumator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is
Add an assembly reference to Microsoft.SqlServer.ForEachFromVarEnumerator.dll and then one can get access to the Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Enumerators.FromVar.ForEachFromVarEnumerator class.

And then the rest of the answer is exactly what @Sam has mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there...I think you are forgetting to set the ForEachEnumerator property of the forEachLoop object.

```
ForEachLoop forEachLoop = p.Executables.Add("STOCK:FOREACHLOOP") as ForEachLoop;
ForEachEnumeratorInfo forEachEnumeratorInfo = runtimeApp.ForEachEnumeratorInfos["Foreach From Variable Enumerator"]; 
ForEachEnumeratorHost forEachEnumeratorHost = forEachEnumeratorInfo.CreateNew();
//forEachEnumeratorHost.CollectionEnumerator = false; // true or false; set accordingly.

// cast the inner object to ForEachFromVarEnumerator
ForEachFromVarEnumerator = forEachEnumeratorHost.InnerObject as ForEachFromVarEnumerator;

// Now that you have the ForEachFromVarEnumerator, set its properties.
// For variable name, do not forget the variable's name space and the variable name (separated by ::)
ForEachFromVarEnumerator.VariableName = "var_namespace" + "::" + "var_name";

// finally.....
forEachLoop.ForEachEnumerator = forEachEnumeratorHost; // DO NOT FORGET THIS. Here you are setting what the actual enumerator would be
```

Comment: Thanks Sam, I knew I had to do this but I was unable to find the ForEachFromVarEnumerator class under Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Enumerators. I realised later that I had to add an assembly reference to Microsoft.SqlServer.ForEachFromVarEnumerator.dll and then would get access to the Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Enumerators.FromVar.ForEachFromVarEnumerator class.

Comment: Cool... for sake of completing the answer; the required dll can be found at C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ForEachFromVarEnumerator\fill-in-sql-version

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

**Script task**

Make sure MyList variable is Writeable

```
  ArrayList NewList = new ArrayList();

            NewList.Add("Ost");
            NewList.Add("Hest");
            Dts.Variables["User::MyList"].Value = NewList;
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

[image]